# What is F1 Score for this diagram?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, measurement, f1

I have this Venn chart that represent a dataset prediction of Identifying if our products are classified as "A41" standard or not

The Blue Circle represents a Machine Learning Model prediction results
The Yellow Circle represents the actual A41 standard classification
The Green Circle represents another method we tried called Mapping.

You can see that the number of products that are not classified as A41 by either method or actually is **2011** and it is outside of all Venn shapes

Now I wanna know what is the F1 score for our model.

How is that?

[image]

Comment: You can add up "Actual" and "Pred" $(2915+567)$, "Actual and not Pred" $(359+1126)$, etc. and then calculate the F1 statistic in the usual way.  Since $567 < 1126$ and $1819 > 127$, I would expect you to find the green model performed better than the blue model.

Comment: @Henry and how to calculate the F1 score in that case?

Answer (score 1):

$F_1 = \frac{2TP}{2TP+FP+FN}=\frac{2(567+2195)}{2(567+2195)+(1819+169)+(359+1126)}=\frac{5524}{5524+1988+1485}\approx0.614$

Where, TP = True Positive, FP = False Positive, FN = False Negative

A downside to using $F_1$ is that it does not consider True Negative values in its calculation, and therefore, you will likely get a different value if you were to swap labels, i.e. estimate the $F_1$ for classifying "!A41". Somewhat related to this is the fact that $F_1$ is sensitive to changes in prevalence. Because of these reasons and a few others, I prefer a metric like the Matthews Correlation Coefficient, [$MCC$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient).